# using a different style for different views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

```
Rails 5.1
```

I mostly work on backend issues, but I am trying to learn more about front end stuff, and I am a little confused about how styles are handled in Rails (I read through a bunch of answers on stackolverflow, but that did not help narrow it down for me).

I have two different views

```
views/user/login.html.slim
views/user/new.html.slim
```

I would like to apply different body styles to each view. When the application was generated, Rails added:

```
assets/stylesheets/users.css.scss
```

Would I need to add a folder, called users and inside it, have different stylesheets? something like this:

```
assets/stylesheets/users/login.css.scss
```

would have in it:

```
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

and

```
assets/stylesheets/users/new.css.scss
```

would have in it:

```
body {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

Then, in

```
stylesheets/application.css.scss
```

I would add:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

Comment: Do you mean creating partials and rendering them from a different page?

Comment: No, I edited my question, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper I agree with your question. I realised Rails is not that good with CSS. Because if we want a CSS file for each style we have to tweak `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>` and create one file for each style and then precompile them all individually. It just makes Rails technique of gathering all CSS in a single master file useless. Actually having a single master CSS is also very bad for website first paint. I am currently breaking my master CSS in tiny pieces after having removed `*= require_self` from `application.css`

Comment: I would be interested to know your final approach.

Comment: For some reason I completely missed the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The styles and javascripts are loaded from your layout.  Out of the box it looks like this:
`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

If you only want to include particular css files in a particular view, you would need to:

- Create a layout for your particular view.
- Include the appropriate styles and javascripts in the layout.
- Specify the particular layout in your controller.

Here is some more information on [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), but lets go through it for your login example.

```
app/controllers/sessions/create

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   layout 'login', only: [:new]
   # you could also call the layout "sessions.html.erb" and it will be 
   # loaded automagically
```

If you want to use a different layout for different actions in the same controller, you can add other layout methods and specify the actions they apply to with the `only` action.

Then the layout

```
app/views/layouts/login.html.erb

...
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'login', media: 'all' %>
...
```

And finally your stylesheet

```
app/assets/stylesheets/login.scss

@import "file_you_want";
```

If you `require_tree .` it will load all styles in the stylesheets directory which I don't think is what you are after.